# Wordpress post layout meta box not saving

Tags: php, wordpress, save, meta

I added the meta box to my post page, so that I can choose what layout I have for each post. I created a meta box, and it's showing, but it won't save.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'post_layout_meta_box' ) ){
    function post_layout_meta_box( $post ){
        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $page_layout = isset($custom["page_layout_left"][0]) ? $custom["page_layout_left"][0] : ( isset($custom["page_layout_right"][0]) ? $custom["page_layout_right"][0] : $custom["page_layout_none"][0] ); 
        ?>
        <p>  
            <select name="page_layout" id="page_layout">
                <option value="left_sidebar" <?php selected( $page_layout, 'left_sidebar' ); ?>>Left Sidebar</option>
                <option value="right_sidebar" <?php selected( $page_layout, 'right_sidebar' ); ?>>Right Sidebar</option>
                <option value="full_width" <?php selected( $page_layout, 'full_width' ); ?>>No Sidebar</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <?php
    }
}


if ( ! function_exists( 'post_save_layout_meta_box' ) ){
    function post_save_layout_meta_box($post_id){  

        if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ){ 
            return $post_id;
        } else{
            if( isset( $_POST['page_layout'] ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $post_id, 'page_layout', wp_kses($_POST['page_layout'], '') ); 
            }
        } 
    }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'post_save_layout_meta_box' );
```

So what am I missing? When I choose Right Sidebar for example, it will return the value to the Left Sidebar after updating a page.

EDIT: Figured it out:

The problem was in this:

```
$page_layout = isset($custom["page_layout_left"][0]) ? $custom["page_layout_left"][0] : ( isset($custom["page_layout_right"][0]) ? $custom["page_layout_right"][0] : $custom["page_layout_none"][0] );
```

It should be

```
$page_layout = isset($custom["page_layout"][0]) ? $custom["page_layout"][0] : 'left_sidebar';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this, in these lines of code there is problem. Wordpress confuse with page_layout_left, page_layout_right.

```
$page_layout = isset($custom["page_layout_left"][0]) ? $custom["page_layout_left"][0] : ( isset($custom["page_layout_right"][0]) ? $custom["page_layout_right"][0] : $custom["page_layout_none"][0] ); 

update_post_meta( $post_id, 'page_layout', wp_kses($_POST['page_layout'], '') );
```

I suggest if you want to use page_layout_left in update_post_meta() function then you should first find what option user selected i.e left or right or full width.

After that in update_post_meta function instead of using page_layout custom field name, use either page_layout_left or page_layout_right like this.

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'page_layout_left', wp_kses($_POST['page_layout'], '') );
```

Hope it may work.

Happy Coding.

Atul Jindal

Comment: Yeah, you were right, my if clause was wrong, I figured it out. Thanks for pointing it out.